# Parallelize a function to run on multiple files

Tags: python, parsing, command-line, parallel-processing

I have a python script (with methods) that parses a .txt file to match some strings. I have four other .txt files, all sitting in the same directory including the original file.  How do I go about parallelizing my code such that I can run the python script on all of them?

Comment: you just need multithreading in your python and a global shared list of files that need to be processed. each thread grabs an entry from this shared list and process the file accordingly. file names can be passed via the argument easily. you may use system.argv

Answer (score 2):

For example using [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

list_of_files = ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4"]

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as e:
    futures = [e.submit(your_parsing_function(f) for f in list_of_files]
```

You can add optional postprocessing logic using `as_completed` method.